# Как получить из тегов xml-файла значения?

Tags: c#, xml

Задача — получить из xml-файла все данные из тега **offer**

Я пробовал получить данные, но оно выдает мне все данные как обычный тест с тегами, а мне нужно получить данные из всех тегов.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<yml_catalog date="2018-05-23 12:00">
    <shop>
        <name>Кальченко Юрий</name>
        <company>ГАЛС-С</company>
        <url>http://www.leoton.ua/</url>
        <currencies>
            <currency id="UAH" rate="1" />
        </currencies>
        <categories>
            <category id="1">Солнечные электростанции</category><!--Автономный инвертор ХТ (1.5кВт-10.0кВт)--> 
            <category id="2">Источники бесперебойного питания</category>
            <category id="3">Измерительная техника</category><!--MPPT Контроллер заряда ИМПУЛЬС-3010S)-->
            <category id="4">Пускозарядные устройства</category>
        </categories>

        <offers>
            <offer available="true" id="3002">
                <url>http://www.leoton.ua/ups-mx2-12-online.php</url>
                <price>11040</price>
                <currencyId>UAH</currencyId>
                <categoryId>2</categoryId>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-1.jpg</picture>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-2.jpg</picture>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-3.jpg</picture>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-4.jpg</picture>
                <name>Источники бесперебойного питания MX (MX2-12)</name>
                <vendor>ГАЛС-С</vendor>
                <description><![CDATA[
                <p>ИБП МХ представляет собой наилучший способ защиты Вашего электрооборудования.</p>
                <p>ON-Line</p>
                <p>•Для серверов и телекоммуникационного оборудования</p>
                <p>•Для Систем ТВ, аудио аппаратуры, ПК и серверов, сетевой аппаратуры</p>
                <p>•Для газовых котлов всех типов</p>
                <p>•Для Кофе-машин и бытовой аппаратуры</p>]]></description>
                <param name="Напряжение АКБ, V">12V</param>
                <param name="Мощность, кВт">1.0 кВт</param>
                <param name="Пиковая мощность, кВт">1.5 кВт</param>
                <param name="Зарядное устройство, А">до 90 А</param>
                <param name="Страна-производитель">Украина</param>
                <param name="Гарантия">1 год</param>
                <stock_quantity>100</stock_quantity>
            </offer>

            <offer available="true" id="3006">
                <url>http://www.leoton.ua/ups-mx3-online.php</url>
                <price>19020</price>
                <currencyId>UAH</currencyId>
                <categoryId>2</categoryId>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-1.jpg</picture>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-2.jpg</picture>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-3.jpg</picture>
                <picture>http://www.leoton.ua/images/mx/mx-4.jpg</picture>
                <name>Источники бесперебойного питания MX (MX3-48)</name>
                <vendor>ГАЛС-С</vendor>
                <description><![CDATA[
                <p>ИБП МХ представляет собой наилучший способ защиты Вашего электрооборудования.</p>
                <p>ON-Line</p>
                <p>•Для серверов и телекоммуникационного оборудования</p>
                <p>•Для Систем ТВ, аудио аппаратуры, ПК и серверов, сетевой аппаратуры</p>
                <p>•Для газовых котлов всех типов</p>
                <p>•Для Кофе-машин и бытовой аппаратуры</p>]]></description>
                <param name="Напряжение АКБ, V">48V</param>
                <param name="Мощность, кВт">2.2 кВт</param>
                <param name="Пиковая мощность, кВт">13.6 кВт</param>
                <param name="Зарядное устройство, А">до 50 А</param>
                <param name="Страна-производитель">Украина</param>
                <param name="Гарантия">1 год</param>
                <stock_quantity>100</stock_quantity>
            </offer>
        </offers>
    </shop>
</yml_catalog>
```

C# код

```
XmlNodeList nodeoffer = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("offer");
string offer = string.Empty;
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeoffer)  
Console.WriteLine(offer=node.InnerText);
```

Comment: Ну а как вы пробовали-то?

Comment: Я код добавил который использовал

Comment: Добавьте ожидаемый результат

Comment: Хочу получить информацию из тегов url,price,currencyId,categoryId тд..То есть хочу получить информацию из всех тегов и записать потом класс или структуру это не важно мне нужен сам алгоритм как это сделать!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для вашей задачи использование `XmlDocument` — не лучший выбор, да и вообще это устаревший способ работы с XML. Если вам нужна большая часть данных из XML — лучше его десериализовать и потом работать уже с полноценными экземплярами классов, если вам из XML нужно извлечь сравнительно малую часть данных — используйте `XDocument` (это более современная замена `XmlDocument`, легковесная и с поддержкой LINQ).

Итак, десериализация. Гуглим "xml to c#", открываем первую ссылку: https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net, вставляем в текстовое поле содержимое вашего XML и жмем Convert, полученный результат копируем в отдельный cs-файл, подправляем пространство имен на нужное нам. Можно вместо онлайн-ресурса воспользоваться встроенным в студию инструментом Edit > Paste Special > Paste XML As Classes, но он выдает более громоздкое представление (с backing fields).

Пишем код:

```
Yml_catalog catalog;
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Yml_catalog));
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
    catalog = (Yml_catalog)serializer.Deserialize(stream);

// Модель можно переписать поудачнее,
//  чтобы св-во Offers сразу было коллекцией
// Сделаете это самостоятельно
var offers = catalog.Shop.Offers.Offer;

foreach (var offer in offers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(offer.Url);
    Console.WriteLine(offer.Price);
    Console.WriteLine(offer.CurrencyId);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо выручили меня

Comment: Слева под кнопками для голосования галочка для принятия ответа. @Vova

Comment: Можно   получить  инфу  из тега <p> я пробывал как не очень.     [XmlRoot(ElementName = "description")]
    public class Description
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "p")]
        public string Text { get; set; }
       
    }

Comment: Тег `p` у вас заключён в `<![CDATA[`, поэтому он воспринимается не как тег, а как содержимое `Description`, его оттуда доставать надо отдельно. С помощью регулярки, например, или опять же с помощью `XDocument`

Comment: @Vova, Проще всего, наверное, вот так сделать: `var pattern = @"<p>(.+)</p>"; foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(offer.Description, pattern)) Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);`

Comment: Спасибо все идеально работает ,я почитал и понял данный шаблон берет все что может  (.+)  в теге  <p> я правильно  понял ?

Comment: Да `.` – любой символ, `+` – один и более раз.